# How to dynamically update TextView text

Tags: android

Inside of a BroadcastReceiver I keep track of each time a list is downloaded and each time it is I want to update a textview with the last time. I have done the following but the time never gets displayed.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
_context = context;
Toast.makeText(context, "ListDownloadReceiver....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .show();

boolean force = intent.getBooleanExtra("FORCE", false);

long nextUpdateTime = getUpdateTime();

if (force || nextUpdateTime < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
    Log.i(LIST_DOWNLOAD_RECEIVER,
        "Going to be downloading the list...");
    DownloadListData downloadList = new DownloadListData(context);
    downloadList.execute();

    } else {
    Log.i(LIST_DOWNLOAD_RECEIVER, "Not connected...");
    context.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(
        ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }
}

DatabaseHandler db = DatabaseHandler.getInstance(context);
String timeFormat = "d/M/yyyy 'at' k:mm:ss";

long lastUpdate = Long.valueOf(db.getPreference("LAST_UPDATED_TIME",
    "0"));

CharSequence time = DateFormat.format(timeFormat, lastUpdate);
Log.i(LIST_DOWNLOAD_RECEIVER, "Time is: " + time);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lastRefreshed);
tv.append("Blah: " + time);

}
```

This is my .xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/noShowsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/blue" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/noShowsTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/no_added_shows"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/refreshButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:contentDescription="@string/refresh"
            android:src="@drawable/refresh"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastRefreshed"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/lastRefreshTime" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:contentDescription="@string/remove_tv_show"
            android:src="@drawable/content_discard" 
            android:clickable="false"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have wrote following line to display text in TextView,

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lastRefreshed);
tv.append("Blah: " + time);
```

I suggest you to use .setText() method instead of .append() method, as follows,

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lastRefreshed);
tv.setText("Blah: " + time);
view.invalidate();  // for refreshment
```

Comment: what is `activity_main` in line `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);` ?

Comment: That, I believe, is referring to the xml layout I posted.

Comment: I thought same , so i checked your xml , there is no id with `activity_main` kindly check it again, it might be referencing to some other .xml file

Comment: Yeah, that crossed my mind too, so I removed android:text="@string/lastRefreshTime" from the textview to ensure it was been called and that updated correctly. Just left blank area instead of Last Updated:...so definitely calling correct xml file.

Comment: setText calls invalidate, you don't need to call invalidate at all after setText

Answer (score 3):

Try following (It worked for me):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tv.setText("Blah: " + time);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The way UI element works in android is that if you want to access elements you must do that in UI thread, and we get data from API or internet related stuff from nonui thread so after getting the result of the nonui thread we can update the UI threads elements easily. you must have seen in logcat that there is too much work in UI thread.It is related to that stuff.Just don't go deep into it If you want to update it programmatically after you are done parsing the data, call the ui thread and update the element.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new thread, inside the run() method, write your code to update the field under consideration, and then start the loop. Do definitely keep in mind that you have to perform the updation operation on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Added OnClickListener and implemented the onClick, using the View parameter and casted to the TextView

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) v;
    textView.setText(crotLoan.getReducedNumber());
}
```

The idea of using onClick, was from [How do you update the screen after you change the text with a setText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695993/how-do-you-update-the-screen-after-you-change-the-text-with-a-settext)